# What is the difference between these two Rust error handling blocks?

Tags: rust, error-handling

I had some code

```
fn read_inner<'b>(&'b mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, Box<dyn Error + 'b>> {
    ...
    buf[rval] = reader.next_spi_byte()?
...
```

that worked in an std environment.  I used the `core_error` crate to make the transition to no_std a little easier.  But now I'm getting errors.

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `Box<dyn core_error::Error>`
  --> /home/thoth/src/rust-esp32-experiments/http-camera/webcam-applib/src/camera.rs:90:47
   |
90 |             buf[rval] = reader.next_spi_byte()?;
   |                                               ^ the trait `From<CamError<<CS as embedded_hal::digital::v2::OutputPin>::Error, ES, EI>>` is not implemented for `Box<dyn core_error::Error>`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <Box<CStr> as From<&CStr>>
             <Box<CStr> as From<CString>>
             <Box<CStr> as From<Cow<'_, CStr>>>
             <Box<T> as From<T>>
             <Box<[T], A> as From<Vec<T, A>>>
             <Box<[T]> as From<&[T]>>
             <Box<[T]> as From<Cow<'_, [T]>>>
             <Box<[T]> as From<[T; N]>>
           and 4 others
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, CamError<<CS as embedded_hal::digital::v2::OutputPin>::Error, ES, EI>>>` for `Result<usize, Box<dyn core_error::Error>>`
```

I tried to work around it a couple of different ways

```
buf[rval] = reader.next_spi_byte().map_err(|e| Box::new(e))?;
buf[rval] = reader.next_spi_byte().map_err(|e| Box::<dyn Error+'b>::new(e))?;
buf[rval] = reader.next_spi_byte().map_err(|e| {
    let tmp: Box<dyn Error + 'b> = Box::new(e);
    tmp
})?;
```

Only the last one actually worked.  The other two triggered errors

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `Box<dyn core_error::Error>`
  --> /home/thoth/src/rust-esp32-experiments/http-camera/webcam-applib/src/camera.rs:91:72
   |
91 |             buf[rval] = reader.next_spi_byte().map_err(|e| Box::new(e))?;
   |                                                                        ^ the trait `From<Box<CamError<<CS as embedded_hal::digital::v2::OutputPin>::Error, ES, EI>>>` is not implemented for `Box<dyn core_error::Error>`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <Box<CStr> as From<&CStr>>
             <Box<CStr> as From<CString>>
             <Box<CStr> as From<Cow<'_, CStr>>>
             <Box<T> as From<T>>
             <Box<[T], A> as From<Vec<T, A>>>
             <Box<[T]> as From<&[T]>>
             <Box<[T]> as From<Cow<'_, [T]>>>
             <Box<[T]> as From<[T; N]>>
           and 4 others
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, Box<CamError<<CS as embedded_hal::digital::v2::OutputPin>::Error, ES, EI>>>>` for `Result<usize, Box<dyn core_error::Error>>`

error[E0599]: the function or associated item `new` exists for struct `Box<(dyn core_error::Error + 'b)>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> /home/thoth/src/rust-esp32-experiments/http-camera/webcam-applib/src/camera.rs:92:81
   |
92 |             buf[rval] = reader.next_spi_byte().map_err(|e| Box::<dyn Error+'b>::new(e))?;
   |                                                                                 ^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `Box<(dyn core_error::Error + 'b)>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
  ::: /home/thoth/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/core-error-0.0.0/src/error_trait.rs:19:1
   |
19 | pub trait Error: Debug + Display {
   | -------------------------------- doesn't satisfy `dyn core_error::Error: Sized`
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `dyn core_error::Error: Sized`
```

Why is the second one different from the last/third one?

The suggestion from isaactfa

```
buf[rval] = reader.next_spi_byte().map_err(|e| Box::new(e) as Box::<dyn Error+'b>)?;
```

appears to work.  It still puzzles me that `Box::<dyn Error+'b>::new(e)` can not be converted to a `Box<dyn Error+'b>` by the `?` operator.

Comment: Can you include the errors the other two gave you?

Comment: The second is different from the other ones because you prevent implicit conversion. That is, in the third example, you say which type you expect, but you leave the compiler the freedom to chose an other generic type for `Box::new` and then perform an implicit conversion. Not sure about the first one though.

Comment: Does `buf[rval] = reader.next_spi_byte().map_err(|e| Box::new(e) as Box<dyn Error + 'b>)?;` work?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially this boils down to how `?` works and how [unsized coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions) work.

Going from `T` to `dyn Trait` (if `T` implements `Trait`) requires an unsized coercion, as does going from `Box<T>` to `Box<dyn Trait>`. The `?` operator does not do unsized coercions, it uses the `Into` conversion trait. It may have worked before with the `std::error::Error` trait since there is an `Into` [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CE%3E) that does the unsized coercion internally `E: Error` to `Box<dyn Error>`. It does not appear that `core_error::Error` has such an implementation, so that's why the first method doesn't work.

The reason `Box::<dyn Error+'b>::new` doesn't work is because you cannot have a variable of type `dyn Trait`. A `dyn Trait` is a [dynamically-sized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/dynamically-sized-types.html) and must be used through some kind of indirection: a reference `&`, a `Box`, etc. Basically you are trying to coerce the type into a trait object too early; `new` would have to accept a `dyn Error` parameter, which is not allowed.

The way the last method works is because you put the value in a `Box<T>` and *then* coerce it to a `Box<dyn Trait>`. Then `?` will work since it will just use the identity blanket implementation of `Into`.